# Failed Building Wheel for cvxopt - Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

Tags: python, windows

I am trying to create a portfolio optimization application in Python for work. One of the required modules is CVXOPT. When I attempt to install the module I get an error that the system is unable to find vcvarsall.bat. I have found several people running into the same issue, and I have tried all of the solutions I could from other posts I saw. I installed the most recent version of Microsoft Visual C++, I have upgraded setuptools...nothing seems to work. Can anyone offer any insight? Here is the output from the command line when I attempt running command "pip install cvxopt:"

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\System32>pip install cvxopt
Collecting cvxopt
  Using cached cvxopt-1.1.8.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: cvxopt
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for cvxopt ... error
  Complete output from command z:\users\mtlagrone\appdata\local\programs\python\
python35\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='Z:\\Users\\MTLA
GR~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-85pwcjv8\\cvxopt\\setup.py';exec(compile(g
etattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__,
 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d Z:\Users\MTLAGR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp02__bk90pip-wh
eel- --python-tag cp35:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cvxopt
  copying src\python\coneprog.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cvxopt
  copying src\python\cvxprog.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cvxopt
  copying src\python\info.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cvxopt
  copying src\python\misc.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cvxopt
  copying src\python\modeling.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cvxopt
  copying src\python\msk.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cvxopt
  copying src\python\printing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cvxopt
  copying src\python\solvers.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cvxopt
  copying src\python\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cvxopt
  running build_ext
  building 'base' extension
  error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for cvxopt
  Running setup.py clean for cvxopt
Failed to build cvxopt
Installing collected packages: cvxopt
  Running setup.py install for cvxopt ... error
    Complete output from command z:\users\mtlagrone\appdata\local\programs\pytho
n\python35\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='Z:\\Users\\MT
LAGR~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-85pwcjv8\\cvxopt\\setup.py';exec(compile
(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file_
_, 'exec'))" install --record Z:\Users\MTLAGR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-yr46es6u-
record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cvxopt
    copying src\python\coneprog.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cvxopt
    copying src\python\cvxprog.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cvxopt
    copying src\python\info.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cvxopt
    copying src\python\misc.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cvxopt
    copying src\python\modeling.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cvxopt
    copying src\python\msk.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cvxopt
    copying src\python\printing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cvxopt
    copying src\python\solvers.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cvxopt
    copying src\python\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cvxopt
    running build_ext
    building 'base' extension
    error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

    ----------------------------------------
Command "z:\users\mtlagrone\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\python.exe -u
 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='Z:\\Users\\MTLAGR~1\\AppData\\Local\\
Temp\\pip-build-85pwcjv8\\cvxopt\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open
', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --r
ecord Z:\Users\MTLAGR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-yr46es6u-record\install-record.tx
t --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in Z:\
Users\MTLAGR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-85pwcjv8\cvxopt\

C:\Windows\System32>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Python library has a native component to it that needs to be compiled using Visual Studio build tools.

According to the [Python documentation](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers), for Python 3.5 (using CPython) you need to install the [build tools](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159) for Visual Studio 2015.

You will need to check the Windows 8.1 and Windows 10 SDK options. When trying to run `pip install` again, [note that](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers#Microsoft_Visual_C.2B-.2B-_14.0_standalone:_Visual_C.2B-.2B-_Build_Tools_2015_.28x86.2C_x64.2C_ARM.29):

> You have to run your commands from Visual C++ Build Tools Command Prompt (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools) each time you want compile with Python.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python 2.7 on windows you'll need the VS2008 compiler - this is the one with which python itself is compiled, and so all the packages. You should get it from here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=44266